# How to add a DELETE button to the "Edit User" Wordpress admin page?

Tags: php, admin

I'm looking for a way to add a DELETE button to the "Edit User" (*/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=???*) page. This is what I have so far but I'd like to place the link next to the "Update User" button.

```
<?php 
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'add_delete_button_to_edit_profile', 10, 1);    

function add_delete_button_to_edit_profile() {
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        echo '<a class="delete_user" href="/wp-admin/users.php?action=delete&user='.$user_id.'&_wpnonce='.$nonce.'>DELETE USER</a>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Note that there is a delete button in the main user list, just recreate that link and add it in a custom user profile field, but keep in mind, plugin recommendations are offtopic here, and any answer you get will require basic technical knowledge, you will need to understand the answer, so basic PHP skills would be assumed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize plugin questions were off topic. Code would be fine if not better. I'll change the question.